# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' linq query

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have this LINQ query:

```
 var query = from row in context.data_vault
             group row by row.STATE into g
             select new {
                 State = g.Key,
                 Count = g.Sum(row => row.SCORE),
                 Phones = g.Count(c => c.PHONE)
             };
```

When executed, I get following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' at g.Count(c =>
>   c.PHONE)

Comment: What do you want to count? You cannot count a string property.

Answer (score 1):

The [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) method expects a function returning a boolean value. It looks like your PHONE property is a string, so this will not work.

What exactly are you trying to count?

Maybe you want all non-empty phone numbers or anything like that, try

```
g.Count(c => !String.IsNullOrWhitespace(c.PHONE))
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to count? If you want to count non-null or non-empty phone numbers, you need to use `g.Count(c => String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.PHONE)==false )`

Answer (score 0):

`Count()` is expecting a predicate - something that returns a boolean.  You've got it returning a string.  I'm not sure what you're after, but if you wanted to count the number of non-blank phones, you would modify it to be

```
 var query = from row in context.data_vault
             group row by row.STATE into g
             select new {
                 State = g.Key,
                 Count = g.Sum(row => row.SCORE),
                 Phones = g.Count(c => c.PHONE != "")
             };
```